# How to add my custom extension in VSCode - OSS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a custom webview extension, I can't upload it to the extension market for some reasons. I want to add this extension into VSCode - OSS and build them as a custom editor. In this custom editor, the extension can be loaded as default when I open the editor.

Could anybody tell me how to achieve this aim, please?
Thanks for replying

Comment: I find 'vsce' can package the extension

Comment: copy the extension directory to the location VSC stores extensions for the user